# Manipulating BeautifulSoup's ResultSet list object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraper

I am trying to extract 2 pieces of data: 1) The value of the option element's "value" attribute (ie "01000.html" below). 2) The string that is within the `<option></option>` tags (ie "Alabama").  There is limited information on the ResultSet list object that is created with I use

`url = 'http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
state_list = soup.find_all("option")`

to extract the list of states from the US Census QFD page's drop-down menu (itself a  element with these options).

Big picture, I was trying to loop through all the counties in the US using a simple i counter, but apparently the counties and States are not numbered uniformly.  I am therefore trying to build a list of these options in order to loop through the "value" (which becomes part of the URL) attributes for the "States (strings)".

```
state_list

[<option value="01000.html">Alabama</option>,
 <option value="02000.html">Alaska</option>,
 <option value="04000.html">Arizona</option>,
 <option value="05000.html">Arkansas</option>,
 <option value="06000.html">California</option>,
 <option value="08000.html">Colorado</option>,
 <option value="09000.html">Connecticut</option>,
 <option value="10000.html">Delaware</option>,
 <option value="11000.html">District of Columbia</option>,
 <option value="12000.html">Florida</option>,
 <option value="13000.html">Georgia</option>,
 <option value="15000.html">Hawaii</option>,
 <option value="16000.html">Idaho</option>,
 <option value="17000.html">Illinois</option>,
 <option value="18000.html">Indiana</option>,
 <option value="19000.html">Iowa</option>,
 <option value="20000.html">Kansas</option>,
 <option value="21000.html">Kentucky</option>,
 <option value="22000.html">Louisiana</option>,
 <option value="23000.html">Maine</option>,
 <option value="24000.html">Maryland</option>,
 <option value="25000.html">Massachusetts</option>,
 <option value="26000.html">Michigan</option>,
 <option value="27000.html">Minnesota</option>,
 <option value="28000.html">Mississippi</option>,
 <option value="29000.html">Missouri</option>,

(etc...)
```

Comment: Bill Letson has the correct answer to the question you asked, but these are [FIPS codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard_state_code). Take the codes from [this EPA page](http://www.epa.gov/enviro/html/codes/state.html) and add '000' to the end, and you have the state codes. (The same EPA page links to state-specific pages, which have the last three digits for each county (e.g., 29 (Missouri) + 019 (Boone County) = 29019 (Boone County, Missouri)).) I also threw [this](https://gist.github.com/myersjustinc/1233434) together a few years ago, in case it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract tag attributes like a dictionary, and access the text with the .text property.

```
for state in state_list:
    print state['value'].split(".")[0], state.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Since iteration is the most probable solution, we can use a simple single liner to convert the object into dictionary or a list of lists.

```
DiCt = {state.text: state['value'] for state in state_list}
LofLists = [[state.text, state['value']] for state in state_list]
```